# I want to use FFT function from ILNumerics Library (open source) exception raised

Tags: vb.net, ilnumerics

I Want to use FFT function from ILNumerics Library but its raising an exception.
What could probably be wrong. I am using VB.NET (VB EXpress 2010)

```
Imports System.Math
Imports OpenTK
Imports ILNumerics.ILMath
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim a As ILNumerics.ILInArray(Of Double) = {10, 20, 30, 40, 89, 90, 98, 90}
    Dim result As ILNumerics.ILRetArray(Of ILNumerics.complex)

    Try
        result = fft(a)
    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim s As Integer
        s = 5 + 5
    End Try



End Sub



<DllImport("ilnumerics_32_x86\mkl_custom.dll")> _
Private Shared Function fft(ByVal a As ILNumerics.ILInArray(Of Double)) As ILNumerics.ILRetArray(Of ILNumerics.complex)

End Function
```

Comment: So why not tell us *what* exception it raises?

Comment: Is the ILNumerics Library Managed .NET code? Then you would not need the DllImport but you can add the Library to the Project's references (like you have already done judging from the Imports statement) and can use it without relying on native DLL imports. Also the exception and more information on what should happen and what doesn't happen is required.

Comment: Please provide the exception that is raised.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to define any dll imports. Just use the commin n- dimensional ILArrays and any of the ILMath.fftXX() functions: http://ilnumerics.net/FFTILMath.html

It works best with the ILNumerics nuget package. it installs all native dependencies automatically and also handles both bitrates (64 vers. 32 bit).

You should also take a look at the documentation on how to use ILNumerics arrays properly: http://ilnumerics.net/FunctionRules.html

Merry Christmas! :)